# WWW.responseHeader["STATUS"] does not exists

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, windows-rt

I already asked on [answers.unity3d](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1081843/www-window-81-missing-first-line-http-header.html) but as there is no response I'll ask on SO too..

I'm not able to retrieve the http status of a response on the [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) object on Windows Phone 8 and Windows RT 8.1 (while it's ok on IOS/Android).

`www.responseHeader["STATUS"]` does not exists and the hidden field `_responseHeaderString` does not contain as first line

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

---

***responseHeaderString*** :

```
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:44:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Sep 2015 11:43:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 07:44:36 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Cache-Control: public
```

***responseHeader*** :

```json
{
    "SERVER"       : "nginx"
    "DATE"         : "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:44:36 GMT"
    "LAST-MODIFIED": "Mon, 07 Sep 2015 11:43:46 GMT"
    "CONNECTION"   : "keep-alive"
    "EXPIRES"      : "Fri, 20 Nov 2015 07:44:36 GMT"
    "CACHE-CONTROL": "public"
}
```

---

**Sample code to reproduce** : (tested on an empty new project)

```csharp
WWW www = new WWW("http://www.google.com");

yield return www;

Debug.Log("Google Status : " + www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey("STATUS")); // False
Debug.Log(www.text); // <doctype ...
Debug.Log(www.responseHeaders["STATUS"]); // KeyError
```

---

Am I missing something or is there someone that can confirm this as a bug ?

**Edit:**
 Still not able to retrieve the http status with the latest [5.3](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.3)

Comment: Just to verify - this is a HTTP(S) request, and not a `file://` or other protocol? The header would suggest HTTP, but these things tend to get emulated in some environments, and I did have this behavior before when using a `file://` protocol on android.

Comment: it's a simple `http` request to download a file, so I need 304/200 information :)

Comment: Does  your www object .error come back without any errors?

Comment: @MXD no, `www.error` is `null`.

Comment: Unity 5.2.2 came out yesterday if you want to give that a try.

Comment: updated the project to 5.2.2 but `STATUS` is still missing :/

Answer (score 1):

Your network server is probably responding with a different (unexpected) response to each device. For various reasons such as the user agent string, which could lead the WWW class to not get the STATUS.

Firstly, I would install a proxy so you can see exactly what the phone sends and what the server raw response is. Either [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (mac/windows) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (windows)  are great.

Here is the actual code that Unity WWW class is using to generate status:

```
        if (num++ == 0 && text.StartsWith("HTTP"))
        {
            dictionary["STATUS"] = text;
        }
```

Ref: https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/WWW.cs#L483

From the proxy it should be clear what is happening. If not, post the request and response here (as raw).

Comment: this code actually use `responseHeaderString` as `text`, and `responseHeaderString` does not contain HTTP status. So the header construction may not fill this condition, I'll re-check when I can with wireshark but I'm sure that the response is the same for each device and is HTTP compliant.

Comment: Unity messes with the response so `responseHeaderString` may not be a true indication of what the server is sending.

Comment: with that wireshark capture, was it running as a proxy and your windows phone was set to communicate via it? can you share the servers URL ?

Comment: I'm working on an IMac so I share the wifi to the devices, like a proxy.  can't share the servers URL, I try to make this bug with a public url and simple code.

Comment: ok, great. Also try fetching your URL with: https://redbot.org (it might show up something incorrect)

Comment: I edited my post with a sample code to reproduce the bug using google

Comment: Wow, that's an insane repro. Anything in www.error ? I don't have a windows phone to verify on.

Comment: www.error is null, as stated in my comment on my post. That's why I asked for bug confirmation too, a simple http request with no weird configuration server side.

Comment: I don't see any bugs like that filed. It would be interesting to know if it is on other windows phones too.  When I'm not using www I use uniweb: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/483

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the www.error before looking for the STATUS header.

```
// Construct the response object
string error = www.error;
if (error == null) {
    if (www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey("STATUS")) {
        string [] status=www.responseHeaders["STATUS"].Split(' ');
        if (status.Length>2 && status[2] != "OK") {
            error = www.responseHeaders["STATUS"];
        }
    }
}
```